# RangeError [EMBED_DESCRIPTION]: MessageEmbed description must be a string

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

This is my code and im getting this error: RangeError [EMBED_DESCRIPTION]: MessageEmbed description must be a string can can someone help me please?

```
const db = require('../models/warns')
const Command = require("../stractures/command");
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "warns",
    aliases: [""],
    description: "Clear messages",
    async run(message, args, client) {
        const user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
        if (!user) return message.channel.send('User not found.')
        const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        db.findOne({
            guildid: message.guild.id,
            user: user.user.id
        }, async (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (data) {
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                embed.setTitle(`${user.user.tag}'s warns`)
                .setDescription(data.content.map((w, i) =>`\`${i + 1}\` | Moderator : ${message.guild.members.cache.get(w.moderator).user.tag}\nReason : ${w.reason}`))
                    .setColor("BLUE")
                message.channel.send({
                    embeds: [embed]
                })
            } else {
                message.channel.send('User has no data')
            }

        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s simply because you are sending an array, rather than a string. Simply joining the array will work

```js
.setDescription(data.content.map((w, i) =>`\`${i + 1}\` | Moderator : ${message.guild.members.cache.get(w.moderator).user.tag}\nReason : ${w.reason}`).join("\n"))
```